# Possible values of "p" in positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem that's asking me for the maximum and minimum possibilities of "p" for this positive semidefinite matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0.8 & 1 \\
0.8 & 1 & p\\
0.8 & p & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

The answer uses the fact that the determinant must be positive. Hence they arrive 0.28 <= p <= 1 which is obvious.

My question is, how do we know there is no other restriction on p? There are many other things to consider like submatrices, eigenvalues, etc. that could be adding additional restrictions to p.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion). In particular, we know that the matrix will be positive *definite* iff the $3$ leading principal minors are positive. Those minors are given by $1$ (which is positive), $1^2 - 0.8^2 = 0.64$ (which is positive), and the determinant of the entire matrix.  Thus, if the determinant of the matrix as a whole is positive, then the matrix must be positive definite.

Incidentally, this criterion is one that you may have already encountered for $2 \times 2$ matrices when studying local extrema in multivariate calculus.

The catch to this approach is that things get a bit tricky when we consider whether or not the matrix is positive *semi*-definite. In particular, we know from the previous paragraph that the values $0.28<p<1$ make the matrix positive definite, but we don't know when the matrix might be positive semidefinite. In this case, there is a convenient approach: because the limit of positive semidefinite matrices is positive semidefinite, we can be sure that the matrix at $p = 0.28$ (i.e. the limit as $p \to 0.28^+$) must also be positive semidefinite. Similarly, it must be positive semidefinite at $p = 1$. In order for a matrix to be positive semidefinite without being positive definite, it must have determinant zero, so because there are no other values of $p$ for which the determinant of the matrix is zero, there are no other values that need to be considered.

More generally, we could test cases where the determinant is zero directly (i.e. test for whether the matrix is positive semidefinite) by considering **every** principal minor of the matrix (as opposed to the leading ones only). Unfortunately, this means that instead of considering $3$ values, we would be considering $7$.

Comment: A more direct approach might be to use the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem): because the eigenvalues of a size $2$ submatrix are positive, the eigenvalues of the whole matrix (which must "interlace" with these submatrix eigenvalues) must consist of at least two positive eigenvalues and at most one eigenvalue that can be negative. Thus, the matrix has a negative eigenvalue if and only if its determinant is negative.